# Mockito thinks parameters of method are null when they are injected with @Context

Tags: junit, mockito, guice

I have a filter called `DynamicAuthFilter` in which I inject an `HTTPServletRequest` and `HTTPServletResponse` object with `@Context`.

```
public class DynamicAuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter, WriterInterceptor {
    private final List<AuthFilter> filters;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;
```

In this class, there is a filter method, which calls a filter method on a list of filters defined in the constructor of the above class.

```
@Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (filters.isEmpty()) {
            // no filters enabled, so no auth is necessary
            return;
        }


        // apply each matching filter
        for (AuthFilter filter : filters.stream()
                                                .filter(f -> f.matchRequest(requestContext))
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList())) {
            appendAuthMethod(requestContext, filter.getName());
            filter.filter(requestContext, request, response);
        }
    }
```

Each of the filters in `filters` subclasses `AuthFilter`. I am trying to test this class in mockito with junit

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DynamicAuthFilterTest {

    @Mock
    private AuthFilter testFilter;

    @Mock
    private AuthFilter testFilter2;

    @Mock
    private ContainerRequestContext requestContext;

    @Mock
    private ContainerResponseContext responseContext;
```

but I am getting an error on the `filter.filter(requestContext, request, response)` in `DynamicAuthFilter`. The test method is:

```
@Test
    public void testRequestFilter_OneFilter_RequestMatch() throws Exception {
        DynamicAuthFilter filter = new DynamicAuthFilter(ImmutableList.of(testFilter));
        HttpServletResponse response = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        when(testFilter.matchRequest(requestContext)).thenReturn(true);

        filter.filter(requestContext);
        filter.filter(requestContext, responseContext);
        filter.aroundWriteTo(writerInterceptorContext);

        verify(testFilter).filter(requestContext, request, response);
        verify(testFilter).filter(requestContext, responseContext);
        verify(testFilter).aroundWriteTo(writerInterceptorContext);
    }
```

The error is

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted: testFilter2.filter( requestContext ); -> at com.company.filter.auth.DynamicAuthFilterTest.testRequestFilter_TwoFilters_OneRequestMatch(DynamicAuthFilterTest.java:100) Actual invocation has different arguments: testFilter2.filter( requestContext, null, null ); -> at com.company.filter.auth.DynamicAuthFilter.filter(DynamicAuthFilter.java:70) 

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
testFilter2.filter(
requestContext
);
-> at com.company.filter.auth.DynamicAuthFilterTest.testRequestFilter_TwoFilters_OneRequestMatch(DynamicAuthFilterTest.java:100)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
testFilter2.filter(
requestContext,
null,
null
);
-> at com.company.filter.auth.DynamicAuthFilter.filter(DynamicAuthFilter.java:70)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.company.filter.auth.DynamicAuthFilterTest.testRequestFilter_TwoFilters_OneRequestMatch(DynamicAuthFilterTest.java:100)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(Unknown Source)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(Unknown Source)
```

How am I supposed to mock `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` when they are injected

Comment: You make mention of  a list of filters defined in the constructor of the above class yet do not show it. The question in its current state is unclear as it is incomplete. Read [ask] and then provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce your problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: You're right the constructor is not included and I'll add it when I can but the constuctor is irrelevant to the question. The question is how to add mock dependencies that are normally injected.

Comment: Following the explicit dependency principle, they should also be injected via the constructor, which is why I wanted to see what the constructor of your class looks like.

Comment: They don't need to be injected by the constructor. That's the point of @Context. Constructor just initializes a filter list